# Delete item is not actually removing it

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I have an edit form that displays items that have been added/stored with the option to delete items. If I click "Delete", the "Save", the success message pops up, but when I go back to the display of the list, the item that I just "Deleted" is still there.

This is the table that displays the items with the delete button beside them:

```
<table id="newPatientForm">
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach:Patients">
            <tr>
                <td class="form-group"><input data-bind="value: FirstName, event: {change: flagPatientAsEdited}, hasfocus: true" /></td>
                <td class="form-group"><input data-bind="value: LastName" /></td>
                <td class="form-group"><button data-bind="click: $parent.deletePatient">Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

This is the viewModel where I declare "PatientsToDelete"

```
using OnboardingProject.Model;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace OnboardingProject.Web.ViewModels
{
    public class SiteViewModel : IModel
    {
        public SiteViewModel()
        {
            Patients = new List<PatientViewModel>();
            PatientsToDelete = new List<int>();
        }

        public int SiteId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string Zip { get; set; }
        public string CreatedOn { get; set; }
        public string ModifiedOn { get; set; }
        public ObjectState ObjectState { get; set; }

        public string MessageToClient { get; set; } // Message sent to client from server to demonstrate data-flow when property is not in db

        // @TODO: Change to client CompleteAddress
        public string CompleteAddress
        {
            get
            {
                return string.Format("{0} {1}, {2} {3}", this.Address, this.City, this.State, this.Zip);
            }
        }

        public List<PatientViewModel> Patients { get; set; }
        public List<int> PatientsToDelete { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is the entire js file:

```
var ObjectState = {
    Unchanged: 0,
    Added: 1,
    Modified: 2,
    Deleted: 3
};

var patientMapping = {
    'Patients': {
        key: function (patient) {
            return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(patient.PatientId);
        },
        create: function (options) {
            return new PatientViewModel(options.data);
        }
    }
};

PatientViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, patientMapping, self);

    self.flagPatientAsEdited = function () {
        if (self.ObjectState() != ObjectState.Added) {
            self.ObjectState(ObjectState.Modified);
        }

        return true;
    },
    self.FullName = ko.computed(function () {
        return (self.FirstName() + " " + self.LastName());
    });
}

SiteViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, patientMapping, self);

    self.save = function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Site/Save/",
            type: "POST",
            data: ko.toJSON(self),
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.siteViewModel != null) {
                    alert("Changes were saved successfully.");
                    ko.mapping.fromJS(data.siteViewModel, {}, self);
                }
                if (data.newLocation != null) {
                    window.location = data.newLocation;
                }
            }
        });
    },

    self.flagSiteAsEdited = function () {
        if (self.ObjectState() != ObjectState.Added) {
            self.ObjectState(ObjectState.Modified); // KO observables are functions & !properties \tf pass value in function
        }
        return true; // Tell KO to allow default action for control that raised this event
    },

    self.addPatient = function () {
        var patient = new PatientViewModel({ SiteId: 0, FirstName: "", LastName: "", ObjectState: ObjectState.Added });
        self.Patients.push(patient);
    },

    self.deletePatient = function (patient) {
        self.Patients.remove(this);

        if (patient.PatientId() > 0 && self.patientsToDelete.indexOf(patient.PatientId()) == -1) {
            self.PatientstoDelete.push(patient.PatientId());
        }
    };
}
```

**UPDATE:** After some debugging, it has come to my attention  that "PatientsToDelete" in the js file is being listed as undefined even though I declare it in the ViewModel. Is there still something I am missing in the js file though?

Comment: In your JS, is there something missing which submits the data to the controller? Seems like everything you're doing is client-side, affecting only the JS array, not the document, and not posting the change back to the server in any way.

Comment: I updated the question with the entire js file.

Comment: Did you step through Save? If so, did you step into `siteViewModel = CreateSiteViewModelFromSite(site);`  Is the new view model correct?

Comment: I started with 2 patients and attempted to delete one while stepping through save. After I "deleted" one, I stepped through save and `Patients : count = 1` so at this point it is only seeing the patient I didn't "delete", but then I kept going through and `PatientsToDelete : count = 0` so it didn't change the patient I click delete on, into a "PatientToDelete"

Comment: @LouFranco I have updated the question with some information I discovered during debugging. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line:

```
self.PatientstoDelete.push(patient.PatientId());
```

You didn't capitalize the T

```
self.PatientsToDelete.push(patient.PatientId());
//           ^--- Capitalize this T
```

Comment: Ugh I hate it when I don't notice type-o's. I guess its true, sometimes you need someone else to take a look. Thanks! It works!